# problem after installing Ubuntu 13.04 on windows 8

Tags: system-installation, windows-8

After installing Ubuntu 13.04 os on my windows8.
after restarting the machine, i provided the user name and passowrd, But its in the command prompt only.
Its not going to show my desktop like windows.

Please help me out of this problem please.

Comment: What happens if you do `sudo startx`?  And, what VGA card do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Which Linux distro did you installed? And which version?

If you installed server edition, it has not desktop environment

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. 
I think its its desktop environment only. Whai i want to do now?

Comment: Try installing XFCE for example: http://www.noobslab.com/2013/07/install-xfce-410-desktop-in-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

When you are at command prompt, try to click `CTRL+ALT+F7`. If nothing changes, try combinations with all F-buttons - it should switch beetween consoles and GUI.